# How can i store result in cache?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, caching, lru

I want to store the result in cache also for a time limit like 24hrs. How can i do it. I tried lru_cache but didn't got right code to do it

```
import json
import IndicatorTypes
from OTXv2 import OTXv2
from OTXv2 import INDICATOR_DETAILS


otx = OTXv2("xxxxx65f25729f6ccb41020174c9aeff3bfe43xxxx2eb3b756ae532xxxxxx")
indicator = '45.148.10.241'

indicator_details = otx.get_indicator_details_full(IndicatorTypes.IPv4, indicator)
obj = indicator_details["url_list"]
obj1 = indicator_details["reputation"]
obj2 = indicator_details["general"]
with open('incoming_data.json', 'w') as data_file:
    json.dump(obj, data_file, indent=4)
    json.dump(obj1, data_file, indent=4)
    json.dump(obj2, data_file, indent=4)
```

Comment: What do you mean by didn't get right way to implement it? It's just a simple decorator that caches a function input and output. You have to convert your main work into a function and then use it if you want to go ahead with `lru_cache`. However, it does not do with time limits, it's based on the the `maxsize`.

Comment: after importing modules all comes in main work, first is my key and then IP which I want to get information and then details which I need from it